# How to force JSON.parse to throw on numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I just discovered that JSON could handle numbers and strings as primitive. I very much wonder why, as I've never seen primitives being used with JSON.

But, to me, parsing primitives using JSON is more likely a programming mistakes (that will go unnoticed) and I'd like to avoid it.

For instance, can I force the following to throw?

`JSON.parse(123);`

Spec: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Why not just create your own parse function and check the type of the input? (Also, you can avoid a lot of these issues if you use a type-safe variant of Javascript or a static type checker.)

Comment: js will stringify the param you give it: `JSON.parse({toString: () => '123'})`

Comment: I agree with "parsing primitives using JSON is more likely a programming mistakes"    
For now you can create a wrapper parser function which checks typeof

Comment: I can understand numbers but what's wrong with strings? Serialized JSON is a string

Comment: *"parsing primitives using JSON is more likely a programming mistake"* - In 99.9% of cases, `JSON.parse()` is used on a `string`, but I believe I understand what you meant. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, `JSON.parse` is used on strings, but what I had in mind that kind of strings `"hi"` which can't be parsed. But my focus is actually on numbers, strings are valid indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `parse` function and check for a `number` argument before deserializing.

```js
(() => {
  const parse = JSON.parse;
  JSON.parse = function (text,reviver) {
    if (typeof text === "number") throw "JSON.parse: Invalid argument type (number)";
    return parse(text,reviver);
  }
})();

console.log( JSON.parse(`{"prop":"Hello world!"}`) );  //OK
console.log( JSON.parse(123) );                        //NOT OK
```

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped there'd be some built-in for this, but that does answer the question :)